# Next.js Links with FC children must pass ref

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

The next.js system documents that when their  component has children that are functional components, then you must pass the ref to that child. I find this to be very confusing and I am having a hard time implementing it.

Let's say that this is a functional component to display a font awesome icon based upon the text entered.

```
const FaIcon:FC<propsObj> = ({icon}):ReactElement => {

  return (
    <>
      { (icon==="Tag") && <FaTag /> }
      { (icon==="QuestionCircle") && <FaQuestionCircle /> }
    </>
)}
```

In this case, attempting to pass the ref to the child component in this form produces an error. (Yes, I used the React.passRef and set it up correctly).

```
<FaTag ref={ref} />
```

It seems that in order for this to work, the child component must have an item that the ref can attach to - like an anchor tag. Doesn't this sort of defeat the purpose of the Link component?

When I "solved" this with ref attached to the anchor tag as below, it produces a typescript error. When the ref is not passed to the anchor tag, it just behaves like a regular anchor tag and reloads the app at the new URL - again what's the point of the Link component wrapper if it doesn't override the anchor tag?

```
const FaIconLink:FC<propsObj> = React.forwardRef(({icon, href}, ref) => {

  return (
    <>
      { (icon==="Tag") && <a href={href} ref={ref} ><FaTag /> </a> }
```

Any help is appreciated. Here is the typescript error.

```
Type 'ForwardedRef<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLAnchorElement> | undefined'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend wrapping your icons within an `a` tag, then you conditionally render children icons/functional components.

```
<Link href={href} passHref>
  <a href={href}>
    {/* conditional icon children here */}
    {children}
  </a>
</Link>
```

Demo:

[image: Edit lucid-khayyam-4oh8q]

Code:

```
import type { CSSProperties, ReactElement, ReactNode } from "react";
import NextLink from "next/link";
import { FaHome } from "@react-icons/all-files/fa/FaHome";
import { FaTag } from "@react-icons/all-files/fa/FaTag";
import { FaQuestionCircle } from "@react-icons/all-files/fa/FaQuestionCircle";
import styles from "./Link.module.css";

export type LinkProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
  className?: string;
  href: string;
  icon: "home" | "question" | "tag" | "none";
  replace?: boolean;
  shallow?: boolean;
  style?: CSSProperties;
};

/* 
   The conditional children below may look a little weird,
   but it's just an inline object using the "icon" as an index:
   
   const iconObj = {
     prop1: <JSX />
     prop2: <JSX />
     prop3: <JSX />
   }  
 
   iconObj["prop1"]

   This is a little less verbose than:
   { icon === "prop1" && <JSX /> }
   { icon === "prop2" && <JSX /> }
   { icon === "prop3" && <JSX /> }

   Optionally you can use a function that returns an icon: 
   {iconType(icon)}

   Or, you can even use an inline IFFE:
   {(() => {
     switch(icon) {
       case "prop1": return <JSX />;
       case "prop2": return <JSX />;
       case "prop3": return <JSX />;
       default: return null;
     }
   })()}

*/
export const Link = ({
  children,
  className,
  href,
  icon,
  replace,
  shallow,
  style
}: LinkProps): ReactElement => (
  <NextLink
    href={href}
    prefetch={false}
    replace={replace}
    shallow={shallow}
    passHref
  >
    <a href={href} className={className} style={style}>
      {icon && (
        <span className={styles.iconLink}>
          {
            {
              home: <FaHome />,
              question: <FaQuestionCircle />,
              tag: <FaTag />,
              none: null
            }[icon]
          }
        </span>
      )}
      {children}
    </a>
  </NextLink>
);

Link.defaultProps = {
  icon: "none"
};

export default Link;
```

Comment: This worked when I wrapped it in the parent div. If I wrapped it in the child functional component, it did not.